# ASP.NET set hiddenfield a value in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I don't know how to set the value of a hiddenField in Javascript.  Can somebody show me how to do this?

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('hdntxtbxTaksit').value = "";
```

HTML:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdntxtbxTaksit" runat="server" Value="" Visible="false">   </asp:HiddenField>
```

> error : "Unable to get value of the property \'value\': object is null or undefined"

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Prior to ASP.Net 4.0**

*ClientID*

Get the client id generated in the page that uses Master page. As Master page is UserControl type, It will have its own Id and it treats the page as Child control and generates a different id with prefix like `ctrl_`.

This can be resolved by using `<%= ControlName.ClientID %>` in a page and can be assigned to any string or a javascript variables that can be referred later.

```
var myHidden=document.getElementById('<%= hdntxtbxTaksit.ClientID %>');
```

- Asp.net server control id will be vary if you use Master page.

**ASP.Net 4.0 +**

*ClientIDMode Property*

Use this property to control how you want to generate the ID for you. For your case setting **ClientIDMode="static"** in page level will resolve the problem. The same thing can be applied at control level as well.

Comment: if you are using Asp.NET User Controls, you can just declare the ClientIDMode when you register on your default page. That way your entire page will have static id. " AKA THE REAL ID'S"

Comment: A side-note in regards to ClientIDMode="static" - Some third-party controls break when you set this property... so be sure to test!

Answer (score 15):

`asp:HiddenField` as:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfProduct" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

js code:

```
$("#hfProduct").val("test")
```

and the code behind:

```
hfProduct.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Format your code properly and give more explanations.

Answer (score 6):

- First you need to create the Hidden Field properly

  `<asp:HiddenField ID="hdntxtbxTaksit" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>`
- Then you need to set value to the hidden field

  If you aren't using [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) you should use it:

  `document.getElementById("<%= hdntxtbxTaksit.ClientID %>").value = "test";`

  If you are using [Jquery](http://jquery.com/), this is how it should be:

  `$("#<%= hdntxtbxTaksit.ClientID %>").val("test");`

Comment: Does the # belong in your example?  It works properly for me without it.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('<%=hdntxtbxTaksit.ClientID%>').value
```

The id you set in server is the server id which is different from client id.

Answer (score 3):

try this code:

```
$('hdntxtbxTaksit').val('test');
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to use [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) rather than the literal ID string in your JavaScript code, since you've marked the field as `runat="server"`.

E.g., if your JavaScript code is in an aspx file (not a separate JavaScript file):

```
var val = document.getElementById('<%=hdntxtbxTaksit.ClientID%>').value;
```

If it's in a separate JavaScript file that isn't rendered by the ASP.Net stuff, you'll have to find it another way, such as by class.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is if you set `controls.Visible = false` during initial page load, it doesn't get rendered in the client response. My suggestion to solve your problem is

Don't use placeholder, judging from the scenario, you don't really need a placeholder, unless you need to dynamically add controls on the server side. Use div, without `runat=server`. You can always controls the visiblity of that div using css.
If you need to add controls dynamically later, use placeholder, but don't set `visible = false`. Placeholder won't have any display anyway, Set the visibility of that placeholder using css. Here's how to do it programmactically :

```
placeholderId.Attributes["style"] = "display:none";
```

Anyway, as other have stated, your problems occurs because once you set `control.visible = false`, it doesn't get rendered in the client response.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use ClientID of HiddenField. first Register its client Id in any Javascript Variable from codebehind, then use it in clientside script. as:

.cs file code:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "clientids", "var hdntxtbxTaksit=" + hdntxtbxTaksit.ClientID, true);
```

and then use following code in JS:

```
document.getElementById(hdntxtbxTaksit).value= "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Javascript value as in `document.getElementByName('hdntxtbxTaksit').value = '0';`