# In ASP with VB codebehind how do I present the user a yes/no dialog from VB

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following case where a user has selected a product, the product record has been retrieved and the backorder flag is set. I want to ask the user if the want to include it in the order anyway. I can't seem to find an exaample anywhere that demonstrates it in an IF statement.

My VB Code Snippet:

```
    Dim backorder = myDataTable.Rows(0)("backorder").ToString()
    If backorder = "True" And <somehow ask user it they want to order anyway> Then
       'do something
    End If
```

My Javascript in aspx file:

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
     function Confirm() {
         var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
         confirm_value.type = "hidden";
         confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
         if (confirm("Selected item is on temporary back order. Do yuou want to include it on this order?")) {
             confirm_value.value = "Yes";
         } else {
             confirm_value.value = "No";
         }
         document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
     }
</script>
```

I can read the variable being added, by javascript, to the page from VB, but can't figure how to call the javascript in order to prompt the user. 
For some reason I can't get my head around this. Please advise with example.

Comment: You're going to have to think about the structure and flow of your application. When does that VB code run?  After the user has already posted the form?

Comment: The form is rendered, the user is entering a part number and the code behind is validating whether the product is valid, back ordered.and a couple other things.

Comment: And at that point, the user's HTTP request is already posted. So if you want to run some JavaScript, you'll have to cancel the rest of your server side execution and show the JavaScript, then have the user repost, then pick up your server side processing again. Which probably doesn't make for a good user experience. It'd be better if you could do this confirmation on the client side before it gets to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `RegisterStartupScript` method:

```
Sub ProcessOrder()

    'Your code to process the selected products here...
    Dim orderAnyway As string = hdnConfirmResponse.Value.Trim()
    If selectedItem.BackOrdered Then            
        If orderAnyway = "" Then
            Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

            ' Define the name and type of the client scripts on the page.
            Dim csname1 As String = "ConfirmScript"
            Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()

            ' Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
            If (Not cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1)) Then
                Dim cstext1 As String = "Confirm();"
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1, True)
            End If
        Else
           If orderAnyway = "yes" Then 
               'ADD THE BACKORDERED ITEM SINCE THEY CONFIRMED 
           End If 
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Forgive me for being dense, but this registers the StartUpScript, how do you call it in the context of my "IF" statement? That seems to be the missing piece in most of the examples I have seen.

Comment: Unless you plan to ajaxify your data calls, you'll need to know which items are backordered when the grid/data table is initially rendered to the browser. What this code will do is produce a client script that will execute `Confirm()` when the page is loaded. So if your current flow is like...User selects a product and triggers a postback, postback retrieves the value of the backorder flag, THEN you want to somehow show the Confirm message, you're in a place where you need 2 postbacks to accomplish what can be done in one if you send this flag out to the table initially.

Comment: The order table is being built by this process, however, it is conceivable to pull a small table (sku and BO status) of back ordered items on startup and check BO status against that... But then I would still have to ask the user...

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem. If you don't know the BO status on first load, tie the code to fire the `Confirm()` popup box in the event handler that adds the items to the order. User selects items and clicks a button to add them to the order, you handle this in your process, and if an item selected is BO, halt processing and write out the script to `Confirm()`, save their choice to a hidden input and check this value when they click the button again.

Comment: So, the user would have to click submit twice?

Comment: Unless you're going to use AJAX, you're stuck with old fashioned postbacks, so yes. See the updates above for an example of how this would work. You can push client script to the browser from the server, but you can't stop server processing, ask for a client value, and send it mid process back to the server with normal ASP.NET postbacks. If that's what you want, you should look in to AJAX.

Comment: mjw you set me on the right path! Thanks.  I tweaked it a bit and posted my solution that worked for me. I had to rework the JS as well.

Comment: Happy to help, if my answer was useful, please show some love. GL

Answer (score 0):

I hate answering my own question but this what finally worked. Mixture of mjw's answer and more research on my javasvript attempt. Rather than have JS create the hidden field, I added it to the HTML

```
    <asp:HiddenField  runat="server" id ="confirm_value"/>
```

New VB:

```
    If myDataTableFrame.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim backorder = myDataTableFrame.Rows(0)("backorder").ToString()
                If backorder = "True" And confirm_value.Value <> "Yes" Then
                    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
                    ' Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
                    If (Not cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(Me.GetType(), "ConfirmScript")) Then
                        Dim cstext1 As String = "Confirm();"
                        cs.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ConfirmScript", "Confirm();", True)
                    End If
                    Return
                Else
                    confirm_value.Value = "No"
                    ...
```

New Javascript:
See [ASP.NET set hiddenfield a value in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454985/asp-net-set-hiddenfield-a-value-in-javascript) Also added a reclick of the button if they answered "OK"

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
     function Confirm() {
         if (confirm("Selected item is on temporary back order. If you want to include it on this order click OK, then resubmit it?")) {
          //had to resort to this to find hidden field rather than document.getElementById('confirm_value')
             var x = document.getElementById('<%= confirm_value.ClientID%>');
             x.value = 'Yes';
             //re-click the button
             document.getElementById('<%=bttnadd.ClientID%>').click();
         } else {
             var x = document.getElementById('<%= confirm_value.ClientID%>');
             x.value = 'No';
         }
     }
</script>
```